# How to get data from 2 api in one function and display in dialogflow card fulfilment

Tags: javascript, get, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm using inline editor fulfillment of Dialogflow to display dynamic data get from API. 
I try to get from 1 API and works fine , now i have to get from 2 in the same time and to show all information in a card.

Here is the code :

```
function GetProductAPI(agent) {
     let prodnr1 =agent.parameters.prodnr1;
const webApiUrl = 'http://www.xxxxxxx.xx/api/products/';   

//  return axios.get(webApiUrl + prodnr1, { headers: {Authorization: `TOKEN zzzzzzzzzzzzz`} })

 axios.all([
 axios.get(webApiUrl + prodnr1, { headers: {Authorization: `TOKEN zzzzzzzzzzzzz`} }),
axios.get(webApiUrl + prodnr1 + '/images', { headers: {Authorization: `TOKEN zzzzzzzzzzzzz`} })
])

 //  .then(res => {
   .then(axios.spread((user1, user2) => {
        const launchData = user1.data;
     const launchData2 = user2.data;
        agent.add(`Product number is:  ${launchData[0].ID}  . Tile is :  ${launchData[0].TITLE}, best price is : ${launchData[0].BEST_PRICE} , image url : ${launchData2[0].IMAGE_URL} `);

     agent.add(new Card({
         title: `${launchData[0].TITLE}`,
        imageUrl: 'https://www.xxxx.xxx/cache/images/product/345345345334.jpg',
        text: `${launchData[0].META_DESCRIPTION}`,
        buttonText: 'Text from api',
        buttonUrl: '${launchData[0].URL}'
      })
     );        
      }));    
}
```

The code that is commented i used just for one API call and works well , now that i try to get from 2 and use the data in one response is not working.
Can you help me to find where is my problem please ?

Comment: can you clarify what do you have problems with?

Comment: @SashaSemanyuk i can't get data from both api in same time , i dont know if the code is ok

Comment: Can you please add what is the response in console? Is there any errors?

Comment: @SashaSemanyuk Error: No responses defined for platform: null
    at V2Agent.sendResponses_ (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js:243:13)
    at WebhookClient.send_ (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:505:17)
    at promise.then (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:316:38)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `return` in front of `axios.all()`.
The working code is `return axios.all([...])`